# Function to find text in a td element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

all,

I have seen several methods on SO here on how I can find the text, or html, written in a td element in a table. For some reason they don't appear to be working for me. I'm obviously doing something quite wrong but I cannot figure out what.

EDIT: The problem is the html() from my td always shows as undefined. I cannot seem to get the text (EG company0) using html(), text(), etc.

Here are my functions. #searchbox is an input type:text

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#searchbox').change(function () {
    var searchText = $(this).val();
    $('.prospect_table tr').each(function () {
        var obj =  $(this).find('.propsect_td');
        if (typeof obj != 'undefined') {
            if (hideText(obj.html(), searchText))
                $(this).show();
            else
                $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
});

function hideText(prospectName, text) {
    if (prospectName == 'undefined')
        return false;

    if (prospectName.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is my source for the page

```
<input type="text" name="txtSearch" id="searchbox" value="Begin typing here..." />

<table class="prospect_table">
<tr>
    <th>
        ProspectName
    </th>
    <th>
        Inactive
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="prospect_td">
        Company0
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="/CrmWeb/Company/Edit/0">Edit</a> |
        <a href="/CrmWeb/Company/Details/0">Details</a> |
        <a href="/CrmWeb/Company/Delete/0">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="prospect_td">
        Company1
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="/CrmWeb/Company/Edit/0">Edit</a> |
        <a href="/CrmWeb/Company/Details/0">Details</a> |
        <a href="/CrmWeb/Company/Delete/0">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

etc...

Any suggestions on how I can improve this and make it work? Maybe I need more id tags as opposed to classes?

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Comment: `prospectName.toLowerCase().IndexOf(...` Please take the time to observe errors in your developer console.

Comment: @squint All I get is that prospectName is undefined.

Comment: Is that exactly what it says? Your `IndexOf` should be `indexOf`.

Comment: made it indexOf instead of IndexOf but it still doesn't get the prospect name

Comment: And yes, because you can't call toLowerCase on an undefined var I believe. So I didn't reach that error yet.

Comment: Then it seems that no element is being located with `$(this).find('.propsect_td');`. Your `typeof obj != "undefined"` test is useless because it'll always be `true`. Do `if (obj.length)` instead.

Comment: ...also `if (prospectName == 'undefined')` doesn't make much sense. Did you mean `prospectName == undefined`? This is why we don't use `typeof` to test for `undefined`. People *constantly* get it wrong.

Comment: It appears then that the examples I drew form were incorrect. I am rather inexperienced in jQuery. Changed that. I just do not understand why it cannot find my elements that clearly exist in the page source.

EDIT: Changed if (prospectName == 'undefined') to prospectName == undefined

Comment: In your `.find()`, you have `"propsect_td"` instead of `"prospect_td"`

Comment: ...here's [a refactoring](http://jsfiddle.net/uosgtq1v/) of your code. It was much more verbose than needed. Your choice of the function name `hideText` is confusing since when it's `true`, you're showing the text, so I changed it and a bunch of other stuff.

Comment: Wow. I feel dumb. Thank you for your patience and help.

Comment: @squint It was a bit verbose and in the original method the hiding was done but I changed it while testing, thus the name. I will change it when I go through and do refactoring. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Changed'.propsect_td' to '.prospect_td', 'IndexOf' to 'indexOf' and replaced typeof obj != 'undefined' with obj.length != 0.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#searchbox').change(function () {
    var searchText = $(this).val();
    $('.prospect_table tr').each(function () {
        debugger
        var obj =  $(this).find('.prospect_td');
        if (obj.length != 0) {
            if (hideText(obj.html(), searchText))
                $(this).show();
            else
                $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
});

function hideText(prospectName, text) {
    debugger
    if (prospectName == 'undefined')
        return false;

    if (prospectName.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#searchbox').change(function () {
    var searchText = $(this).val();
    $('.prospect_table tr').each(function () {
        var obj =  $(this).find('.prospect_td');

        console.log(obj.text());
        if (typeof obj != 'undefined') {
            if (hideText(obj.text(), searchText))
                $(this).show();
            else
                $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
});

function hideText(prospectName, text) {
    if (prospectName == 'undefined')
        return false;

    if (prospectName.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Few typos fixed... and rather than html() i use text() property. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bn1403nk/

Comment: It is working inside fiddle, please re-check -> your event is CHANGE, if you want instant change, use keyup....

Comment: I will change it to keyup because I do want an instant check.

Comment: @nevermind: You should explain in detail what you changed. If the OP didn't see a typo to begin with, he probably won't spot the correction.